# Why am I getting "Error processing transaction request: intrinsic gas too low" error when trying to add tUSDT to a particular account?

Tags: java, ethereum, go-ethereum, erc20, web3-java

I am trying to send test USDT to a particular account in Java using the following [code](https://github.com/mentiflectax/minimal-crypto-exchange/blob/i16/process-engine/src/main/java/com/dpisarenko/minimalcryptoexchange/delegates/TransferUsdtToExchangeAccount.java):

```
final Web3j web3 = createWeb3If(ethNetworkUrl);
final Credentials credentials = Credentials.create(privateKey);
final ERC20 usdtContract = ERC20.load(usdtContractAddress, web3, credentials, new TestGasProvider());

usdtContract.transfer(exchangeAddress, BigInteger.valueOf(10)).send();
```

The last statement results in the following exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error processing transaction request: intrinsic gas too low
    at org.web3j.tx.TransactionManager.processResponse(TransactionManager.java:176)
    at org.web3j.tx.TransactionManager.executeTransaction(TransactionManager.java:81)
    at org.web3j.tx.ManagedTransaction.send(ManagedTransaction.java:128)
    at org.web3j.tx.Contract.executeTransaction(Contract.java:367)
    at org.web3j.tx.Contract.executeTransaction(Contract.java:350)
    at org.web3j.tx.Contract.executeTransaction(Contract.java:344)
    at org.web3j.tx.Contract.executeTransaction(Contract.java:339)
    at org.web3j.tx.Contract.lambda$executeRemoteCallTransaction$3(Contract.java:410)
    at org.web3j.protocol.core.RemoteCall.send(RemoteCall.java:42)
    at com.dpisarenko.minimalcryptoexchange.delegates.TransferUsdtToExchangeAccount.execute(TransferUsdtToExchangeAccount.java:57)
```

[TestGasProvider](https://github.com/mentiflectax/minimal-crypto-exchange/blob/i16/process-engine/src/main/java/com/dpisarenko/minimalcryptoexchange/logic/usdt/TestGasProvider.java) is defined as:

```
public class TestGasProvider extends StaticGasProvider {
    public static final BigInteger GAS_PRICE = BigInteger.valueOf(10L);
    public static final BigInteger GAS_LIMIT = BigInteger.valueOf(1L);

    public TestGasProvider() {
        super(GAS_PRICE, GAS_LIMIT);
    }
}
```

`usdtContract` was deployed using [this script](https://github.com/mentiflectax/minimal-crypto-exchange/blob/i16/erc20/npm-prj/deploy-USDT.sh), which calls [deploy.js](https://github.com/mentiflectax/minimal-crypto-exchange/blob/i16/erc20/npm-prj/scripts/deploy.js):

```
async function main() {
  const USDT = await ethers.getContractFactory("USDT");
  const usdt = await USDT.deploy(1000000000000000);

  console.log("USDT contract deployed to:", usdt.address);
}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

This contract is running on a local testnet set up as described [here](https://dpisarenko.com/mce/en/how-to-start/).

What do I need to change in any of these components (testnet, contract, deploy scripts, Java code) in order to send any amount of USDT to a particular address (without any errors)?

*Update 1:* If I change `TestGasProvider` to

```
public class TestGasProvider extends StaticGasProvider {
    public static final BigInteger GAS_PRICE = BigInteger.valueOf(1L);
    public static final BigInteger GAS_LIMIT = BigInteger.valueOf(1000000000L);

    public TestGasProvider() {
        super(GAS_PRICE, GAS_LIMIT);
    }
}
```

I get another error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error processing transaction request: exceeds block gas limit
    at org.web3j.tx.TransactionManager.processResponse(TransactionManager.java:176)
    at org.web3j.tx.TransactionManager.executeTransaction(TransactionManager.java:81)
    at org.web3j.tx.ManagedTransaction.send(ManagedTransaction.java:128)
    at org.web3j.tx.Contract.executeTransaction(Contract.java:367)
    at org.web3j.tx.Contract.executeTransaction(Contract.java:350)
    at org.web3j.tx.Contract.executeTransaction(Contract.java:344)
    at org.web3j.tx.Contract.executeTransaction(Contract.java:339)
    at org.web3j.tx.Contract.lambda$executeRemoteCallTransaction$3(Contract.java:410)
    at org.web3j.protocol.core.RemoteCall.send(RemoteCall.java:42)
    at com.dpisarenko.minimalcryptoexchange.delegates.TransferUsdtToExchangeAccount.execute(TransferUsdtToExchangeAccount.java:57)
```

## Update 1

I am looking to submit a set of code changes to the branch [i16](https://github.com/mentiflectax/minimal-crypto-exchange/tree/i16) of the `minimal-crypto-exchange` project which passes the following test:

### Step 1

Set up the environment as described [here](https://dpisarenko.com/mce/en/how-to-start/).

### Step 2

Set a breakpoint on line `usdtContract.transfer(exchangeAddress, BigInteger.valueOf(10)).send();` in [TransferUsdtToExchangeAccount](https://github.com/mentiflectax/minimal-crypto-exchange/blob/i16/process-engine/src/main/java/com/dpisarenko/minimalcryptoexchange/delegates/TransferUsdtToExchangeAccount.java) class:

[image: Screenshot of the code part with breakpoint]

### Step 3

Start the process engine application in debug mode. Its Java main method is located [here](https://github.com/mentiflectax/minimal-crypto-exchange/blob/i16/process-engine/src/main/java/com/dpisarenko/minimalcryptoexchange/MinimalCryptoExchangeProcessApplication.java).

Wait until you see the message `starting to acquire jobs` in the console output:

```
11:59:16.031 [JobExecutor[org.camunda.bpm.engine.spring.components.jobexecutor.SpringJobExecutor]] INFO  org.camunda.bpm.engine.jobexecutor - ENGINE-14018 JobExecutor[org.camunda.bpm.engine.spring.components.jobexecutor.SpringJobExecutor] starting to acquire jobs
```

### Step 4

Login with the credentials `demo/demo` at http://localhost:8080.

[image: Screenshot of the login form]

After login you should see a page like this:

[image: Main Camunda dashboard with tasklist link highlighted]

### Step 5

Click on the tasklist link. You should see a page that looks like this:

[image: "Start process" link the tasklist]

Press the "Start process" link. Following screen will appear:

[image: "Start process" dialog box with "Send USDT to the exchange account" process highlighted]

Click on `Send USDT to the exchange account process` link. Following dialog box will appear:

[image: "Start process" dialog]

Enter an arbitrary value into the "business key" field and press the "Start" button.

### Step 6

After a couple of seconds, the breakpoint from step 2 will activate.

The problem will be solved if `usdtContract.transfer(exchangeAddress, BigInteger.valueOf(10)).send()` is executed without errors.

### Notes

1. You are allowed to modify the amount in `usdtContract.transfer(exchangeAddress, BigInteger.valueOf(10)).send();` from `10` to something else.
2. You can also modify the parameters of the Ethereum testnet specified in [docker-compose.yml](https://github.com/mentiflectax/minimal-crypto-exchange/blob/i16/docker-compose.yml) and [genesis.json](https://github.com/mentiflectax/minimal-crypto-exchange/blob/i16/genesis.json), as well as those of the USDT smart contract which is deployed using [this script](https://github.com/mentiflectax/minimal-crypto-exchange/blob/i16/erc20/npm-prj/deploy-USDT.sh).
3. Your solution must work in this controlled environment (i. e. no faucets must be used).

## Update 2

I made following changes:

1. The [set-up tutorial](https://dpisarenko.com/mce/en/how-to-start/) now contains step 7 in which ETH is added to the exchange account.
2. Now a new version of the [ETH testnet](https://github.com/mentiflectax/geth-poa-testnet) is being used, major changes being that log output is more verbose and the gas price is set to 1 (see `--miner.gasprice 1` in [entrypoint.sh](https://github.com/mentiflectax/geth-poa-testnet/blob/master/entrypoint.sh)).
3. Modified the code in [TransferUsdtToExchangeAccount](https://github.com/mentiflectax/minimal-crypto-exchange/blob/i16/process-engine/src/main/java/com/dpisarenko/minimalcryptoexchange/delegates/TransferUsdtToExchangeAccount.java) so that now USDT is transferred not from the exchange account (which has zero balance), but from the buffer account.

Now I am receiving the error

```
org.web3j.protocol.exceptions.TransactionException: Transaction 0x4bce379a2673c4564b2eb6080607b00d1a8ac232fbddf903f353f4eeda566cae
has failed with status: 0x0. Gas used: 32767. 
Revert reason: 'ERC20: transfer amount exceeds allowance'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My skills with Ethereum are still not sharp enough to give you a proper answer, but I hope you get some guidance.

The error states that you are trying to transfer by a party A certain quantity in the name of another party B, to a third one C, but the amount you are trying to transfer, using `transferFrom`, is greater than the one party B `approved` party A to send.

You can check the actual `allowance` between to parties using the method with the same name of your contract.

Please, consider review [this integration test](https://github.com/web3j/web3j/blob/master/integration-tests/src/test/java/org/web3j/protocol/scenarios/HumanStandardTokenGeneratedIT.java) from the web3j library in Github. It is different than yours but I think it could be helpful.

Especially, it states that the actual `transferFrom` operation should be performed by the beneficiary of the allowance. Please, see the relevant code:

```java
final String aliceAddress = ALICE.getAddress();
final String bobAddress = BOB.getAddress();
ContractGasProvider contractGasProvider = new DefaultGasProvider();
HumanStandardToken contract =
        HumanStandardToken.deploy(
                        web3j,
                        ALICE,
                        contractGasProvider,
                        aliceQty,
                        "web3j tokens",
                        BigInteger.valueOf(18),
                        "w3j$")
                .send();

//...

// set an allowance
assertEquals(contract.allowance(aliceAddress, bobAddress).send(), (BigInteger.ZERO));

transferQuantity = BigInteger.valueOf(50);
TransactionReceipt approveReceipt =
        contract.approve(BOB.getAddress(), transferQuantity).send();

HumanStandardToken.ApprovalEventResponse approvalEventValues =
        contract.getApprovalEvents(approveReceipt).get(0);

assertEquals(approvalEventValues._owner, (aliceAddress));
assertEquals(approvalEventValues._spender, (bobAddress));
assertEquals(approvalEventValues._value, (transferQuantity));

assertEquals(contract.allowance(aliceAddress, bobAddress).send(), (transferQuantity));

// perform a transfer as Bob
transferQuantity = BigInteger.valueOf(25);

// Bob requires his own contract instance
HumanStandardToken bobsContract =
        HumanStandardToken.load(
                contract.getContractAddress(), web3j, BOB, STATIC_GAS_PROVIDER);

TransactionReceipt bobTransferReceipt =
        bobsContract.transferFrom(aliceAddress, bobAddress, transferQuantity).send();

HumanStandardToken.TransferEventResponse bobTransferEventValues =
        contract.getTransferEvents(bobTransferReceipt).get(0);
assertEquals(bobTransferEventValues._from, (aliceAddress));
assertEquals(bobTransferEventValues._to, (bobAddress));
assertEquals(bobTransferEventValues._value, (transferQuantity));

//...
```

This fact is also indicated in [this OpenZeppelin forum post](https://forum.openzeppelin.com/t/transferfrom-always-reverts-with-revert-erc20-transfer-amount-exceeds-allowance/3993).

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. While debugging my setup I found out that the core issue was that the exchange account did not have any USDT tokens. I fixed this by modifying the [contract](https://github.com/mentiflectax/minimal-crypto-exchange/commit/c63e7d9b5ec1b6d34d434f4d9afcc8171b61e423#diff-f4431bcb935c5ac92bc74954021c755f7fc7ed1d6d1c91b3c1b1967412115396) so that when it is [deployed](https://github.com/mentiflectax/minimal-crypto-exchange/blob/i16/erc20/npm-prj/scripts/deploy.js), the exchange account gets some USDT.

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback. You are very welcome @DmitriiPisarenko. I am happy to see that the answer was helpful and that you managed to successfully run the exchanges. Having said that, mate, I'm sorry I can't give you a better, more complete, solution.